# Is this the right use of primitive wrapper class?

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive

I have the following code:

```
public final class MedianOfTwoSortedArrays {  
    private MedianOfTwoSortedArrays() {}

    private static boolean isMedian (int[] a1, int[] a2, int pos) {
        if (pos == 0 || pos == (a1.length - 1)) return true;
        return (a1[pos] >= a2[pos]) && (a1[pos] <= a2[pos + 1]);
    }

    public static Double median (int[] a1, int[] a2) {
        if (a1.length != a2.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The argument thrown is illegal");

        int lb = 0;
        int hb = a1.length - 1;

        while (lb <= hb) {
            int a1Median = (lb + hb)/2;
            int a2Median = (a2.length - 1) - a1Median;

            if (isMedian(a1, a2, a1Median) || isMedian(a2, a1, a2Median)) {
                return (a1[a1Median] + a2[a2Median])/2.0;
            }

            if (a1[a1Median] < a2[a2Median]) {
                lb = a1Median + 1;
            }

            if (a1[a1Median] > a2[a2Median]) {
                hb = a1Median - 1;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a1 = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
        int[] a2 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
        System.out.println("Expected 5.5, Actual " + median (a1, a2));


        int[] a3 = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 100};
        int[] a4 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 200};
        System.out.println("Expected 6.5, Actual " + median (a3, a4));

        int[] a5 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int[] a6 = {5, 6, 7, 8};
        System.out.println("Expected 4.5, Actual " + median (a5, a6));

        int[] a7 = {5, 6, 7, 8};
        int[] a8 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        System.out.println("Expected 4.5, Actual " + median (a7, a8));  
    }
}
```

The function `median` returns a primitive wrapper `Double` rather than `double`  simply because it's forced to do so.

If median is not found then returning `-1` may not be the right choice since, `-1` may also be a valid median. In this case, unlike binary search, I dont return a index of an array and dont want to do it either.

Last option which I have is to throw an exception. But coming to my question: is function `median` a valid use of a primitive wrapper of just an unwanted hack?

Comment: Could you edit your post with the code? Not just a link, please.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't change the return value to double?

Comment: I think this is a classic example that gives motivatation for the "wrapper class" `Double`.  Not only is it not a "hack" as you fear, but it's quite common.

Comment: Can you give an example of when you wouldn't have a median? I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what that situation would be.

Comment: Also: this is offtopic here. You specifically ask for a codereview AND you posted it first on codereview.se. Why did you crosspost it here?

Comment: I posted it for code review for reviewing entire code, I posted it here for a very specific question.

Comment: @chrylis the median of [2,4,6,8] is *sometimes* defined as 5 (the mean of 4 and 6), but this may not always be desirable since 5 is not actually in the set.

Comment: another option: return a result object that has `isValid()` & `.getDoubleValue()` methods, guava's [`Optional`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) serves similar purposes.

Comment: @chrylis if the input arrays are not sorted median would not be obtained.

Comment: Then that's a violation of the contract, and you should throw `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: agree but this code is without javadoc, check this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39560/find-the-mean-of-the-medians-of-two-equal-sized-sorted-arrays?noredirect=1#comment66339_39560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's fine. Your other choice is to create a wrapper object like

```
class MedianAnswer {
  boolean success;  
  double median;
}
```

and return that instead, and to check `medianAnswer.success` to see if it found the median.

An additional option is to throw MedianNotFoundException and to catch it. You do similar with IllegalArgumentException.